# App store App, iPad PRO app icon scaled or missing

Tags: ipad, icons, app-store, ios-simulator, asset-catalog

I use Xcode 7.1 and don't see anywhere in images.xcassets to add the iPad PRO sizes app icon. Nobody seems to know how to add an app icon for iPad Pro. Apple documents say nothing either for app icon on iPad PRO.

Running iPad PRO simulator, the app icon is scaled from iPad Air version. However, on the app store, will the iPad PRO icon also be scaled from iPad Air version or will the app icon be missing?